# The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int64' and 'System.Decimal'

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I have this weird problem in Linqpad that "sometimes" that I try to do a query like this:

```
decimal  appId = 8463054;
var pp = APPLICATIONS.Where(a => a.APPLICATION_ID == appId);
pp.Dump();
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException
The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int64' and 'System.Decimal'.
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: well it's not working with a `long` or `System.Int64`

Comment: @roryap how I can rebuild in Linqpad?!

Comment: @Hooman -- No idea.  Never heard of it.

Comment: What exactly is `APPLICATIONS`?  Comparing a `decmial` to a `long` shouldn't throw an exception, but maybe whatever Linq provider you are using doesn't like that.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884141/the-binary-operator-multiply-is-not-defined-for-the-types-system-int32-and-sy) seems related as it's likely that your lambda is being turned into an expression.

Comment: Just going to throw this out there.  Have you tried closing and reopening LinqPad?  I had a weird compilation issue with LinqPad once that I resolved this way.

Comment: @JasonBoyd it was worth a try but no it didn't solve it

Comment: What type of connection is it? LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework or IQ?

Comment: @JoeAlbahari Hey! Thanks for checking Linqpad questions Joe! Great software by the way. Well, I was trying to do that linq query as a LINQ  to Oracle DB, but after you comment I also tried a Linq to Entity Framework and it worked.

Comment: Do you get the same error is you just do APPLICATIONS.ToList() ? That's what's happening in my query - seems there is something in the definition of the table that linqpads IQDRiver does not like.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
long appId = 8463054; // long is just a keyword for System.Int64
```

There's no need to declare it as a decimal, as you aren't using fractional digits anyway.

Comment: well I understand what you did there but I'm getting the same error even with a `long` or `System.Int64`

Comment: You're getting an error that still refers to `System.Decimal`?  Did you rebuild?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error and no, I didn't rebuild since I'm using Linqpad not VS

Comment: Well I don't know Linqpad.  But in VS, you sometimes have to rebuild to get rid of earlier compiler errors.

Comment: @Hooman If this change didn't fix it then there seems to be an issue with LinqPad.  Maybe you could try turning it off and on again?

Comment: this does not solve the problem, why is it marked as solved? I have the same problem, it's weird. Linqpad and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that appId is decimal. Just declare it as long:

```
long  appId = 8463054;
var pp = APPLICATIONS.Where(a => a.APPLICATION_ID == appId);
pp.Dump();
```